# Support for Touch.radiusX on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, canvas, touch

Does anyone have any idea how well supported the property is?
Specifically, I'm using the PR0C0D1N6 app on an iPhone 4 and according to the spec, radiusX will always be 1 if it's not supported but in my case, radiusX is undefined.

I don't think it has anything to do with the app itself since I'm pretty sure it just inserts the javascript and opens it in the native browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch.radiusX

This is the property in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current support (Oct 14, 2012) is limited to Firefox and Chrome on Android.

Both of them are supporting these new [touch event v.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/) properties with vendor prefixes.

I have read that Chrome desktop will support it as well, but you have to turn it on in the about:flags area.  And of course you need the touch screen hardware too.

We'll probably have to wait for a whole new iOS version before we see it in Mobile Safari, unfortunately.